# Zip Files one by one Or All of them together

Tags: c#, .net, gzip

I use `GZip` in `C#`. I have multiple files to zip and put them together.
But i don't know if i zip files one by one then save them in a file is better than make a file from them, and finally zip the created file only.
How about the size of the produced File?Which one is better to producing smaller file size ?

Comment: "Better" how? Resulting file size? Speed at which your code executes.. ? What?

Comment: Generally i mean, i haven't implementation experience

Comment: Better in general? ... that's subjective.

Comment: There are just 2 options - why not to try it yourself and compare based on your criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to optimize on file size, putting them in one zip file might be a bit better, depending on the data in the files; the exact settings used, etc.

If you are looking to optimize on running time, and the library you're using is single-threaded, then you can potentially get a large performance bump by zipping each file in its own thread, but that assumes that Gzip is processor bound, which it might well not be.

Overall, the results will probably be subjective, and very dependent on the data you're trying to compress. Your best option would likely be to grab a sample of somewhat representative files, GZip them a few different ways, and see which way works best for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I try to implement the options on two image file and the result is :

Image1 6kb + Image2 7kb = 13kb

Image1Compressed 3kb + Image2Compressed 3kb = 6kb

In this sample there are no difference.
So it's better to use 2nd option.